# Rendering array data with a condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to make a large number of `inputs` and transfer this data to the server, I decided that the best solution would be to write all the options of these `inputs` into an `array` of `objects`, but I ran into the fact that I can’t get all my `inputs` to work. help me please

```
  const test = [
    {id: 1,state: 'city'},
    {id: 2,state: 'language'},
    {id: 3,state: 'brand'},
    {id: 4,state: 'shop'},
  ]
const Auth = () => {
  const [description, setDescription] = useState({city: "", language: "", brand: "", shop: ""});

const handleClick = async (event: any) => {
      await store.update(description.city, description.brand);
  };

const update = async (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      setDescription({
        ...description,
        city: e.target.value
      });
  };

return (
        <>
          {test.map(({ state, id}) => (
                <TextField
                    key={id}
                    label={state}
                    id={state}
                    autoComplete="off"
                    variant="outlined"
                    className={styles.textFieldAuth}
                    helperText={state}
                    value={description.city}
                    onChange={update}
                />
          ))}
             <Button
              className={styles.saveButton}
              variant="contained"
              color="inherit"
              id="login"
              onClick={handleClick}
             >
              Save
              </Button>
        </>
)
}
```

Comment: @Andy It's not that important, just a test on which I'm trying to solve the problem. Perhaps you have a solution for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You send to TextField description.city for every input. The correct props are like so:

```
                 <TextField
                    key={id}
                    label={state}
                    id={state}
                    autoComplete="off"
                    variant="outlined"
                    className={styles.textFieldAuth}
                    helperText={state}
                    value={description[state]}
                    onChange={update}
                />
```

See the change in the `value` prop.

Also, you only update city in the update function. You have to make it so that the update function adapts to what values you pass to it. If you pass the city then it should update the city, if the language then the language and so on.

Overall this is not a good way to implement inputs. I just suggest you do them one by one and send to each TextField its corresponding value and a separate setState for each one.

But just for the sake of the example. The way you can do it is by passing the state value to the `Update` function.

So your function will look like this:

```
const update = async (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>, state) => {
      setDescription((description) => {
        ...description,
        [state]: e.target.value
      });
  };
```

Now you just need to make sure that in the TextField component when you call `onChange`, you pass to it the event `e` and `state` which you have received from props.

Note: If you want to use the value of a state variable in the setState itself, pass to it a callback function like I did in the `setDescription`

Comment: Using a config file to create inputs is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @Andy Sure, but only if you have many pages with many inputs in a complex project - but in that case just use a library like Formik or something. If you just have a page with 4 inputs, creating a config is just over-engineering and trying to look smart. Especially if you need to pass for each one a different setState.

Comment: Not necessarily. I used config files for all my toy projects too, and they're not that complicated.

Comment: @AlexMatei Typescript says that the problem is with the value type. TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Description'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Description'

Comment: @wannnwdooo Yes. The type of the variable description is not a string. Since you did not create an interface for the state values, just add `:any` to the description variable. But make sure to type it properly in the future.

Comment: In order not to give ts errors, I used value={description[state as keyof typeof description]}

Answer (score 1):

Pass both the key that you want to update and the value to the `update` function:

```js
const update = (key: string, value: string) => {
    setDescription({
        ...description,
        [key]: value,
    });
};


{test.map(({ state, id }) => (
    <TextField
        key={id}
        label={state}
        id={state}
        autoComplete="off"
        variant="outlined"
        className={styles.textFieldAuth}
        helperText={state}
        value={description[state]}
        onChange={(e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
            update(state, e.target.value)
        }
    />
))}
```

Comment: You forgot the value prop.

Comment: Will the solution be universal if passed to value description.city?

Comment: It should be `description[state]` then.

Comment: In order not to give ts errors, I used value={description[state as keyof typeof description]}

Answer (score 1):

if you want to make it dynamic you would have to send the variable to save to your update method and retrieve your value with description[state]

```
  <TextField
    key={id}
    label={state}
    id={state}
    autoComplete="off"
    variant="outlined"
    className={styles.textFieldAuth}
    helperText={state}
    value={description[state]}
    onChange={(e)=>update(e, state)}
  />



 const update = async (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>, state) => {
          setDescription({
            ...description,
            [state]: e.target.value
          });
    };
```

Comment: Typescript says that the problem is with the value type. TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Description'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Description'

Comment: In order not to give ts errors, I used value={description[state as keyof typeof description]}

Answer (score 1):

I think first and foremost you need your configuration data to try and closely match the elements you're building. So instead of `{ id, state }` use `{ id, type, name }`.

(This may not have a huge effect on your example because you're specifically using a `TextField` component, but if you were using native HTML controls you could add in different input types like number, email, date etc, and your JSX could deal with it easily.)

Second, as I mentioned in the comments, you don't need for those functions to be `async` - for example, there's no "after" code in `handleClick` so there's no need to `await` anything.

So here's a working example based on your code. Note: I've stripped out the Typescript (because the snippet won't understand the syntax), and the references to the UI components you're using (because I don't know where they're from).

```js
const { useState } = React;

// So, lets pass in out inputs config
function Example({ inputs }) {
  
  // I've called the state "form" here as it's a little
  // more meaningful
  const [form, setForm] = useState({});

  // `handleSave` is no longer `async`, and for the
  // purposes of this example just logs the updated
  // form state
  function handleSave() {
    console.log(form);
    // store.update(form);
  }

  // Also no longer `async` `handleChange` destructures
  // the name and value from the changed input, and updates
  // the form state - a key wrapped with `[]` is a dynamic key
  // which means you can use the value of `name` as the key value
  function handleChange(e) {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setForm({ ...form, [name]: value });
  }

  // In our JSX we destructure out the id, name, and
  // type properties from each input object in the config
  // and apply them to the various input element properties.
  return (
    <div>
      {inputs.map(input => {
        const { id, name, type } = input; 
        return (
          <input
            key={id}
            type={type}
            name={name}
            placeholder={name}
            value={form[name]}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        );
      })}
      <button onClick={handleSave}>Save</button>
    </div>
  );

}

// Our updated config data
const inputs = [
  { id: 1, type: 'text', name: 'city' },
  { id: 2, type: 'text', name: 'language' },
  { id: 3, type: 'text', name: 'brand' },
  { id: 4, type: 'text', name: 'shop' }
];


ReactDOM.render(
  <Example inputs={inputs} />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```